# Watch pattern with PathModified/PathChanged but ignore several files and folders

Tags: systemd

I would like my service to watch changes inside a folder `/path/to/projectname` except for changes happening to a virtualenv located at `/path/to/projectname/venv`.

The architecture of files inside `/path/to/projectname` is the following:

```
.
├── README.md
├── scripts
├── setup.py
├── src
└── venv
```

I have the following systemd.path file:

```
[Path]
PathModified=/path/to/projectname

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I noticed the existence of `PathExistsGlob` in the [systemd.path docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html). But I did not notice anything about ignoring a globbing pattern for `PathModified` or `PathChanged`.

I could also write this:

```
[Path]
PathModified=/path/to/projectname/scripts
PathModified=/path/to/projectname/src
PathModified=/path/to/projectname/setup.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but I feel like there could be a better way.

Is there a way to watch a folder except for one (or more) particular children of this folder?